# R graphic - select the axis

Tags: r, graphics, axis

I want to plot a graphic in R, but the actual values of the axis are the following values:
0,1,2,3,4,....,400

I would like to plot the graphic with the following values:
0,1,2,3,4,5,***6-50,51-100,100-200,200-400***

So I will have space to see all the graphics.

My code to plot the graphic is

```
 freq %>%
+   arrange(time_open_limit) %>%
+   ggplot( aes(x=time_open_limit ,y=percentage2,fill=time_open_limit)) +
+   geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Thank you for your time

Julen

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. For me it is not quite clear what you are asking. Could you provide a sample of your data (freq) and explain the desired outcome in more detail?

Comment: Try `scale_x_discrete(breaks = <your breaks>)`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my poor explanation.
I we have the following table, there are three variables
open_time, the number of people and the percentage.

|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|      time open (in seconds)  | Number people    | Percentage     |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             1                |       100        |        1%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             2                |       200        |        2%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             3                |       300        |        3%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             4                |       400        |        5%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             5                |       500        |        6%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             6                |       600        |        7%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             7                |       700        |        8%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             8                |       800        |        9%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             9                |       900        |       10%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             23               |       1000       |       12%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             24               |       1100       |       13%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|             200              |       2000       |       23%      |
|------------------------------|------------------|----------------|

If I run the following code:

```
library(readxl)
tb <- read_excel("location_of_the_table/data_example.xlsx", 
                           col_types = c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
colnames(tb)

tb %>%
     ggplot( aes(x=time_open_seconds ,y=Percentage,fill=Percentage)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

You will see a graphic with values between 1-9,
 then a gap , values for `time open` 23,24,
 then a big gap and values for `time open` 200.

My question is if I could have a graph showing values for:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,23-24,">25".
So the graphic will have 11 values, one for each number betwen 1-9, and then will will
group 23 and 24 in one value, and then greater than 25 ( it will show the value `time open`=200).

Have I explained myself??

Really thank you for your time

Julen